# Indicating keyworded-ness of arguments in NumpyDoc DocStrings?

Tags: python, docstring, numpydoc

In trying to follow the NumpyDoc format for my DocStrings, I can't seem to figure out how to tell the user that an argument is a keyword argument (ie. specified as `SomeFunc(theKeyWordArg=100)` as opposed to `SomeFunc(100)` ).

The documentation I've found online (such as [this](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_numpy.html) and [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/HOWTO_DOCUMENT.rst.txt)) only show examples such as

```
def somefunc(arg1, arg2):
'''
Parameters
----------
arg1, arg2 : int
    info on arg1 & arg2
```

and for keywords arguments:

```
def somefunc( keyword=False ):
...
```

but says that for the general case, which is what I have defined in many of my functions:

```
def somefunc( *args, **kwargs):
```

that I should document them as so:

```
Parameters
----------
*args
    Variable length argument list.
**kwargs
    Arbitrary keyword arguments.
```

The problem I'm having is that I don't see a clear way to tell the user which arguments in the *Parameters* section are keyworded vs. unkeyworded, so I'd have to do something like the following:

```
somefunc(*args, **kwargs)
'''
Parameters
----------
x : int
    Non-keyworded arg, x is an int
name : string
    keyworded arg, pass a string as the name.
'''
```

So a user would call the function to set `x` & `name` like so:

```
somefunc(10, name='gazebo')
```

Is there no way standard way to indicate in the docstring which arguments are keyworded & which aren't?

---

For example, wouldn't this be a good way to make it clear?

```
somefunc(*args, **kwargs)
'''
Parameters
----------
x : int
    x is an int
y : float
    y should be a float
name = string
    Pass a string as the name
label = string
    Provide a label for this object
'''
```

where `:` means it's non-keyworded (ie. `SomeFunc(100, 200)`) and `=` means keyworded (ie. `SomeFunc(100, 200, name="Bob", label="one and two hundred")`)

Answer (score -3):

When an argument is a keyword argument in Python it therefore has a default value (setting aside some unusual handling of `**kwargs`). Usually it suffices (and keeps the documentation simpler) to just state what the default is, e.g.:

```
def somefunc(keyword=False):
    """
    Parameters:
    -----------
    keyword: bool. Controls whether to delete hard drive. Defaults to False.
    ...
    """
    # ... rest of code
```

From this, the reader must know that any argument with a default value is a keyword argument.

This is the style in some larger libraries, such as pandas. Here is some of the help string for `pandas.ols`:

```
Definition: pandas.ols(**kwargs)
Docstring:
Returns the appropriate OLS object depending on whether you need
simple or panel OLS, and a full-sample or rolling/expanding OLS.

Will be a normal linear regression or a (pooled) panel regression depending
on the type of the inputs:

y : Series, x : DataFrame -> OLS
y : Series, x : dict of DataFrame -> OLS
y : DataFrame, x : DataFrame -> PanelOLS
y : DataFrame, x : dict of DataFrame/Panel -> PanelOLS
y : Series with MultiIndex, x : Panel/DataFrame + MultiIndex -> PanelOLS

Parameters
----------
y: Series or DataFrame
    See above for types
x: Series, DataFrame, dict of Series, dict of DataFrame, Panel
weights : Series or ndarray
    The weights are presumed to be (proportional to) the inverse of the
    variance of the observations.  That is, if the variables are to be
    transformed by 1/sqrt(W) you must supply weights = 1/W
intercept: bool
    True if you want an intercept.  Defaults to True.
nw_lags: None or int
...
```

Comment: Ah, that's interesting.  However, I have many functions with non-keyworded args that also have something like a "default value", so many of those defaults are mentioned in the docstring.

Comment: Also, this func *only* takes kwargs, so it's clear that every arg should be keyword `pandas.ols( x=[1,2,3], y=whatever)`.  It just occurred to me that the mapltolib `plot()` function is very similar to mine - taking both °args and °°kwargs.  Looking at their documentation, they avoid the *Parameter* section entirely and just verbosely explain the whole thing.  Pending further evidence, I suspect there is *no* standard way to concisely tell a user that one param is a *arg and another is a **kwarg. Replacing the `:` with an `=` would be a concise way tho... I assume that breaks the sphinx thing?

Comment: Actually, is there anything bad about stating `x = int` for a °°kwarg & `y : float` for a °arg?  Seems like a reasonable way to indicate keywordedness.

Comment: I don't normally associate matplotlib with best practices in Python, but then again Pandas isn't the greatest example either. I'm puzzled by your statement 'I have many functions with non-keyworded args that also have something like a "default value"' ... it's bad practice to just rely on a conventional default value. Is there any good reason you can't make all of those positional arguments into keyword argument with their representative defaults? That would be much better in terms of not breaking the API down the road.

Comment: Well, if the user never called the `set_thisVar(x)` function, when the program sends commands to another piece of software later in the process, if has to use some value, hence `get_thisVar()` returns a "default" value.  This module was originally programmed with non-keywarded args, which makes it really simple and fast for the user to use.  I have had to add numerous optional args, which I did as keyword args (since otherwise there are more than 2 or 3 positional args, which gets confusing quickly in this case).  <<too long>>

Comment: If I delete the capability for positional args, existing users' scripts will all fail - I want to keep it backwards compatible (and the positional-args is actually really nice for basic usage - only advanced usage finds utility in kwargs).  This is all pretty tangential to the actual question tho, although I appreciate your interest in improving my code.  It seems like there is **No accepted way to document that a Param is positional vs. keyworded** - so far the only suggestions are to not code that way - I don't think functionality should be sacrificed due to a lacking documentation standard.